# Android - Different colors in different devices

Tags: android, colors, background

I'm developing an application for Android, and the colors of drawables changes when I'm testing the app on Samsung Galaxy S2, and when I test the application on Samsung Galaxy Europe or on emulator, appears the real colors of the drawable. For exemple, the gradient white and black, is different on Samsung S2.

Why this happening?? Can I do something on application to show the real colors on Samsung S2?

Comment: Can you post the screenshots here for both the devices??

Comment: are you using your drawables or are you using the drawables offered by android?

Comment: check both brightness and contrast and also check another app how it behaves.

Comment: Ok, I found it... was the brightness of the device! On the screen mode, the Dynamic option make images to much bright! So, is something that depends of choice of user... Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when we use transparent images in our app mostly the transparent part will show its parent.

For example if we use transparent images for menus in android.
then by default the theme of the device/background will be the parent view for this image.
According to me better to change the image and try.